# Angular ssr error after upgrading from Angular 16 to 17

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular17

I upgrade my angular 16 project with schematics ng update.

a server.ts.bak was generated, i dont know what is it? But most important my server.ts has an error it dont recognize express() (see image below)?

[image]

Has anyone successfully migrated angular ssr 16 to 17? How to fix this?

Comment: Are your dependencies all installed ? (did you run `npm install` ?)

Comment: Please favor posting the actual text instead of pictures of text when possible.  Your error is not searchable.

Comment: try `import {default as express} from 'express';`